# Godot debug window not triggering area2d signals

Tags: godot

[Video of what's happening exactly](https://youtu.be/EcC9-2wGY58)

Specs are:

- Display being recorded 2560x1080@60hz
- Display that the window goes offscreen 3840x2160@24hz (tested with 60hz too)
- Windows 10
- GPU Nvidia 970 GTX

Just started learning godot this week and lost hours to this strange behavior.

Godot specifics:

- Scale of shapes and bodies are not modified (not to mess with physics)
- Starting out trying to create an Entity class, that extends KinematicBody2D, to create instances of enemies within my game. Just using the dummy block for now to test if collisions are indeed working (stopped here due to what happened on the video)
- The big dummy square that has one square texture is said Entity, with a collision with huge Y size just to test things out.
- The area2d I want to trigger the signal is the small rectangle in front of the character.

Is there something I should know that is causing the signal to only fire while the debug window is on the other display? Should I just move the debug window to the other display and trust the game will work?

Code snippets

Creation of Area2D inside my animation controller

```
func _create_shape_with_collision(s : Shape2D, parentNode : Node) -> Node:
    var ret = Area2D.new()
    ret.connect('body_entered', self, '_check_body_entered')
    var c = CollisionShape2D.new()
    c.shape = s
    parentNode.add_child(ret)
    c.disabled = true
    c.name = 'collision_shape'
    ret.add_child(c)
    return ret
```

signal function

```
func _check_body_entered(body : Node):
    print(body.name)
```

PS: Attempted to type some stuff to help with autocomplete within Godot's interface, but my created classes were not working properly.

PS2: posted this same message on godot's reddit page, in hopes of better visibility

Comment: Looks like a bug in Godot. The video says you are using Godot 3.2.3. At the time of writing there is a release candidate for Godot 3.2.4 [here](https://godotengine.org/article/release-candidate-godot-3-2-4-rc-5), the release candidate has some known issues, but also a lot of bug fixes. Try your project there. If it   also has the same problem, consider opening an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues). A minimal project with the problem is encouraged.

Comment: @Theraot as it seems to work in display 1 (godot window in display 2), I set the debug window to open on display 1 and everything seems to work smoothly, so far. Can I trust it to work like that, if I ship an executable for the game?

Comment: Is your target platform the same you develop on? If yes, I'd expect it to work the same. Furthermore, you can go ahead export it and test it. Otherwise, there is no replacement for testing on the target hardware. I don't have a multi monitor setup to test for you. I don't expect anybody with a single monitor to face this problem. I want to reiterate my previous comment. First, Godot betas and release candidates are good. I have used them in production. Just remember to test. We are now at the brink of a new stable. And second, if this has not been fixed already, it should, open an issue.

Comment: ok, i tested it: exporting on current stable, debugging and exporting on the 3.2.4-RC5 and the issue persists. Guess its time to open an issue. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because @Theraot laid a path towards writing an issue on Godot's Github page, I was able to determine the cause of the above *bug*, while creating a minimal project.

In fact, it does not relate at all with the code, but on project settings. The physics FPS was set at 60, while my secondary screen was able to capture the event, as VSYNC was also on by default (caps FPS at refresh rate, secondary screen is 24hz).

Increasing the physics FPS to 120 (empyrical at this point) made the signal work on all displays.

Will gladly accept a better answer, explaining what are the impacts of changing such number (the strain on devices etc), if it is a bad practice or if there is another way to configure individual faster ticks for Area2Ds or PhysicsBody2Ds. Could not write such answer due to my current lack of knowledge/research. Trying to write it at this point would be a sophism.

Since i'm just coding some basic game elements while writing a Game Design Document, it's so far so good for me.

Edit:

After an insight from user @Theraot, I overlooked how different _process and _physics_process worked; For my use case, most of what I was doing should be inside _physics_process, so I could revert the engine's physics FPS back to default value.

Comment: My intuition is that you are doing something that changes physics in `_process` and thus tied to actual frame rate. `_physics_process` should run at the configured physics rate, and thus not be affected by the current monitor. Which makes me think there must be some code that if you move from `_process` to `_physics_process` would make your project work without the need to increase physics rate. I'm guessing that is where you enable/disable the collision area. Hopefully you can figure it out and improve your answer.

Comment: Hello again @Theraot. Thank you very much for this insight. Indeed the AnimationController I was working had some stuff tied to _process. Changing it to _physics_process made everything work (after reverting the physics fps to default), and I even took the time to test stuff out lowering and raising the physics FPS to check if behavior was the same. I believe this is a powerful tool to check if the game is working as intended (since everything moves very slowly, its easy to see flaws in the logic or if I had any oversights with the engine's physics, as I'm not very familiar with it).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a matching Collision layer and mask in the Area2D node.
Shape2D is a resource, meaning if you don't create .new() then all CollisionShape2D are using the same instance of the shape. If anyone sets explicitly it free it's gone for everyone (so try printing if you accidentally are assigning a null shape). There's some weirdness on resizing after assigning not happening when CollisionShape2D is ready.
But also you have `c.disabled = true` that probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: hey mate thanks for your answer - im using collision layers and mask as 1 for everything, not touching the default setting. Also, im disabling collisionshapes2d on attach due to another part of the script toggling it as disabled = false when its needed (like frame 2 of the sword attack, as seen in the video link above). In fact, the debug shows the area goes blue (enabled) when issuing the command. (also im creating a new collisionshape2d for every kinematicbody2d / area2d im using, since this seems to work in my current pipeline.